# Form and Html tag not working laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I am new to laravel 5.2 framework and founding it difficult to configure the Form and Html packages into directory, I have gone through the documentation and followed each line, but still I get the same error. Class "Form" not found.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dlRw.png

This is my example view, this is how Im using form tag.

```
{!!Form::open(array('url' => '' , 'method' => 'get'))!!}
  {!! Html::link( url( '/frontend/posts/like',$post->id ), 'Like',     ['class' => 'btn btn-primary like-btn', 'data-status' => 'like' ] ) !!}
  {!! Html::link( url( '/frontend/posts/like', $post->id ), 'Dislike', [ 'class' => 'btn btn-primary like-btn', 'data-status' => 'dislike' ] ) !!}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

I have included the following things in app.php file

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

(in providers)

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

(in aliases)

I have this in my composer.json-

```
"require": {"laravelcollective/html": "^5.2"},
```

I have used composer update command and composer dump-autoload, But still my problem is not solved yet. Please anyone help me.

Comment: Please verify if the actual files have installed. From the root directory of your project look for `vendor/laravelcollective/html/src/FormFacade.php`.

Comment: Please share the same examples but including 3 lines above and below each section you originally shared.

Comment: @Qevo, I have checked inside my vendor folder, I do have vendor/laravelcollective/html/src/FormFacade , HtmlFacade.php and many more files..

Comment: Please share the same examples but including 3 lines above and below each section you originally shared.

Comment: `"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9 <6.0.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
    },`

...Show more context.

Comment: {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. `composer update`
2. `php artisan cache:clear`
3. `php artisan config:clear`
4. `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: But, when I use artisan config:clear command, all the pages starts giving 500 internal error, I think It deletes all configurations.

Comment: This from the help *config:clear - Remove the configuration cache file*, so it just cleans the cache storage. What is the error you get?

Comment: I ran this command php artisan config:clear, After that, my code was not running. All  pages went white screen and gave 500 internal server error in firebug. When I tried to run

Comment: @PrashJ *500 internal server error* could be anything, be more specific. Your installation is correct, there should be no problem for you to use this packege.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following `artisan` command:

```
php artisan optimize
```